# Find the count of unique FK associated with two or more Col2 values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I’m trying to find a way to get a count of unique foreign keys that are associated with at least two different Col2 values across multiple rows. Example:

| PK | Col2 | FK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | page1 | abc |
| B | page2 | abc |
| C | page1 | fgd |
| D | page2 | mnl |

I want to find the count of unique FK associated with BOTH Page1 and Page2 for a large amount of data. Any advice on the most efficient way to do this?

Edit: thanks for the responses and follow up. I will try to clarify: the desired result of the query I need for this table would be 1 (the number of unique values of FK that are associated with both page1 and page2). The question I’m looking to answer is essentially how many users hit page1 and also hit page2 in the same session. Each hit is a unique key under PK and whether they belong to the same session is determined by the key under FK.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Just to be clear, do you want 3 results from your data (i.e. abc 2, fgd 1 & mnl 1) or what, exactly? Please clarify if I haven't got it right!

Comment: What column output do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function for this, no self-joins are needed.

```sql
SELECT *,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FK)
FROM YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7cb4e363a018d44faf05433f126fb6ff)

For efficiency you will want an index with `FK` as the leading key column.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FK)
FROM Table
WHERE FK IN (
    SELECT FK
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY FK
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) > 1
)
```

As for performance on a large table, I can't advise on that without knowing the table definition and indexes that exist on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you only want the unique count of `FK` values, and only for when the same value exists for both `page1` and `page2`. I believe the following query accomplishes that:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T1.FK) -- unique count of shared FK values
FROM YourTable AS T1
INNER JOIN YourTable AS T2
    ON T1.FK = T2.FK -- Join where they share the same FK...
    AND T1.Col2 = 'page1' -- ...and T1 is only page1...
    AND T2.Col2 = 'page2'; -- ...and T2 is only page2
```

For maximizing performance, I'd recommend the following index for the above query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourTable_FK_Col2 ON YourTable (FK, Col2);
```

If you really wanted to get crazy, you even try making it a filtered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourTable_FK_Col2_Filtered ON YourTable (FK, Col2) WHERE Col2 IN ('page1', 'page2');
```

Though this may be overkill and at best have negligible performance gains compared to the previously mentioned index. It also limits the usability of the index if you ever wanted to ask the same query for other values of `Col2`. But if you always are only going to run this query for `page1` and / or `page2` then you may find this index better, otherwise the first index I mentioned would be the way to go.

Comment: That's how I understood him as well. It looks like you're getting the same results as mine. However, I think he only used Page1 and Page2 is an example, so I'd think the query needs to just look for counts where the FK exists with two or more Col2 values. But maybe I'm interpreting his question wrong.

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey Yea, I'm not sure exactly what OP is expecting, waiting to see if he updates his question or responds to my comment.